# Python Attribute Error for Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I've made a tree with: mytree[3]="red" mytree[4]="blue" mytree[6]="yellow" mytree[2]="at". But if I try to delete the root node, 3, with mytree.delete(3), I get an AttributeError.  'TreeNode' object has no attribute 'findSuccessor'. Any idea why this happens?

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,key,val,left=None,right=None,parent=None):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def isLeftChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self

    def isRightChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.rightChild == self

    def isRoot(self):
        return not self.parent

    def isLeaf(self):
        return not (self.rightChild or self.leftChild)

    def hasAnyChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild or self.leftChild

    def hasBothChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild and self.leftChild

    def replaceNodeData(self,key,value,lc,rc):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = value
        self.leftChild = lc
        self.rightChild = rc
        if self.hasLeftChild():
            self.leftChild.parent = self
        if self.hasRightChild():
            self.rightChild.parent = self


class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def length(self):
        return self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def put(self,key,val):
        if self.root:
            self._put(key,val,self.root)
        else:
            self.root = TreeNode(key,val)
        self.size = self.size + 1

    def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):
        if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)

    def __setitem__(self,k,v):
        self.put(k,v)

    def get(self,key):
        if self.root:
            res = self._get(key,self.root)
            if res:
                return res.payload
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def _get(self,key,currentNode):
        if not currentNode:
            return None
        elif currentNode.key == key:
            return currentNode
        elif key < currentNode.key:
            return self._get(key,currentNode.leftChild)
        else:
            return self._get(key,currentNode.rightChild)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __contains__(self,key):
        if self._get(key,self.root):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def delete(self,key):
        if self.size > 1:
            nodeToRemove = self._get(key,self.root)
            if nodeToRemove:
                self.remove(nodeToRemove)
                self.size = self.size-1
            else:
                raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')
        elif self.size == 1 and self.root.key == key:
            self.root = None
            self.size = self.size - 1
        else:
            raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')

    def __delitem__(self,key):
        self.delete(key)

    def spliceOut(self):
        if self.isLeaf():
            if self.isLeftChild():
                self.parent.leftChild = None
            else:
                self.parent.rightChild = None
        elif self.hasAnyChildren():
            if self.hasLeftChild():
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    self.parent.leftChild = self.leftChild
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = self.leftChild
                    self.leftChild.parent = self.parent
            else:
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    self.parent.leftChild = self.rightChild
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = self.rightChild
                    self.rightChild.parent = self.parent

    def findSuccessor(self):
        succ = None
        if self.hasRightChild():
            succ = self.rightChild.findMin()
        else:
            if self.parent:
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    succ = self.parent
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = None
                    succ = self.parent.findSuccessor()
                    self.parent.rightChild = self
        return succ

    def findMin(self):
        current = self
        while current.hasLeftChild():
            current = current.leftChild
        return current

    def remove(self,currentNode):
        if currentNode.isLeaf(): #leaf
            if currentNode == currentNode.parent.leftChild:
                currentNode.parent.leftChild = None
            else:
                currentNode.parent.rightChild = None
        elif currentNode.hasBothChildren(): #interior
            succ = currentNode.findSuccessor()
            succ.spliceOut()
            currentNode.key = succ.key
            currentNode.payload = succ.payload

        else: # this node has one child
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                    currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild
                elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                    currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.leftChild
                else:
                    currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.leftChild.key,
                                    currentNode.leftChild.payload,
                                    currentNode.leftChild.leftChild,
                                    currentNode.leftChild.rightChild)
            else:
                if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                    currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.rightChild
                elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                    currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                    currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.rightChild
                else:
                    currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.rightChild.key,
                                    currentNode.rightChild.payload,
                                    currentNode.rightChild.leftChild,
                                    currentNode.rightChild.rightChild)




mytree = BinarySearchTree()
mytree[3]="red"
mytree[4]="blue"
mytree[6]="yellow"
mytree[2]="at"
mytree.delete(3)

print(mytree[6])
print(mytree[2])
```

Comment: You seem to expect `BinarySearchTree` to inherit from `TreeNode` (you call methods on `self` inside the BST class that are from `TreeNode`), but it does not. In addition, how is your tree constructed (I.E. actual code)? The error you're getting is pretty explicit; An object of type `TreeNode` is having methods from `BinarySearchTree` applied to it. Since your `BinarySearchTree` class inserts `TreeNodes` instances into itself rather than `BinarySearchTree` instances, this makes sense.

Comment: In short, I suggest that you go over your code again and make sure you're referencing `TreeNodes` where you mean to reference `TreeNodes` and `BinarySearchTrees` where you mean to be referencing `BinarySearchTrees`

Comment: Deleting leaves works, but nothing internal.

Comment: Well, it doesn't inherit, right?  But BinarySearchTree just has a pointer to our root node and the methods inside it, which then has children nodes that point to each otehr all the way down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `findSuccessor` on an instance of `TreeNode` in `BinarySearchTree.remove`.  Your implementation of `TreeNode` does not have a `findSuccessor` method, but your `BinarySearchTree` class does.  Either add a method `findSuccessor` to `TreeNode`, or edit your `remove` method to call the `findSuccessor` method on a `BinarySearchTree`.

Adding to `TreeNode`:

```
class TreeNode:

    # ...Omitted code

    def findSuccessor(self):
        succ = None
        if self.hasRightChild():
            succ = self.rightChild.findMin()
        else:
            if self.parent:
                if self.isLeftChild():
                    succ = self.parent
                else:
                    self.parent.rightChild = None
                    succ = self.parent.findSuccessor()
                    self.parent.rightChild = self
        return succ

    def findMin(self):
        current = self
        while current.hasLeftChild():
            current = current.leftChild
        return current
```

or perhaps you meant for `BinarySearchTree` to inherit from `TreeNode`:

```
class BinarySearchTree(TreeNode):
    # ...Omitted code...
```

In which case you could just replace your references to the `TreeNode` class with `BinarySearchTree` references.

```
class BinarySearchTree(TreeNode):

    ####  OMITTED CODE #####

    def put(self,key,val):
        if self.root:
            self._put(key,val,self.root)
        else:
            self.root = BinarySearchTree(key,val)  ### switched TreeNode for BinarySearchTree
        self.size = self.size + 1

    def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):
        if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                currentNode.leftChild = BinarySearchTree(key,val,parent=currentNode)  ### switched TreeNode for BinarySearchTree
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                currentNode.rightChild = BinarySearchTree(key,val,parent=currentNode)  ### switched TreeNode for BinarySearchTree

   ########## Omitted Code #######
```

Either will work. I am a bigger fan of the latter.

Comment: It works! Thanks for ACTUALLY helping me out! I really appreciate it.